# Using Excel Solver for conference schedule optimisation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to use Excel Solver to optimize the schedule of a conference. The end goal is that every conference session is thematically coherent, and sessions are grouped by subject.

I created a hypothetical situation in which I have 20 research papers to divide over 5 sessions, with 4 papers per session each. 5 subjects are covered, each by 4 of the research papers.

The Excel sheet I created looks like this.

[image]

I've tried to use Excel Solver to figure out the optimal setting in which the one session would cover all papers with subject 1, the next session all papers with subject 2, and so on.

Cells I25:M29 show which topics are covered in one session.

Right now the objective is to maximise $N$30. This sums cells I30:M30, which counts if one of the subjects in a session sums up to 4, e.g. COUNTIF(I25:I29,4).

This is done by changing Variable Cells I2:M21, which is a binary variable for every paper to be allocated to one session.

Constraints I've entered:

- Papers per session shouldn't exceed the maximum of 4
- I2:M21 are binary
- Every paper should be allocated to a session, i.e. N2:N21 = 1

[image]

Problem is: I can't get this to work properly. I've tried multiple options, e.g. evolutionary, GRG nonlinear, but none of them give the obvious solution, which is this:

[image]

What are your thoughts on this, what Solver parameters would guide me towards this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just sort of figured out how to make this work.

1. $N$30 should be the sum of all subjects, which adds up to 20 (and actually allows for linear programming)
2. Constraints should be entered for each session to have 1 topic by entering that the subject should be the same as the maximum number of spots per session, $I$26 = $I$23, $J$27 = $J$23, etc.

Visually:

[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pyZx.png)

[image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Xur.png)

However, when I would want to add a lot more sessions, this will become quite laborious, so any alternatives are still very welcome!